# How to have signature on bottom of page, but ensure it isn't the only item on the page

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, xetex, positioning, signatures

I have a series of tables (of varying lengths) on a page(s) and then a spot for a signature (which needs to be on the bottom of the page) That is working well, however sometimes the signature ends up being the only item on the page which just looks odd. In this case I would like the last table to also be pushed on to the next page but up the top. Which I have no idea how to do

```
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
    \arrayrulecolor{tableHeadings}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{tableHeadings} \textcolor{white}{Academic Subjects}}  \\
    \hline
        Mathematical Methods&2016\\
        Chinese Second Language&2015\\
        Chemistry&2016\\
        Specialist Mathematics&2016\\
        English as an Additional Language&2016\\
        German&2016\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \vspace{1cm}

       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
     \arrayrulecolor{tableHeadings}
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{tableHeadings} \textcolor{white}{House Participation}}  \\
     \hline
        Mathematical Methods&2016\\
        Chinese Second Language&2015\\
        Chemistry&2016\\
        Specialist Mathematics&2016\\
        English as an Additional Language&2016\\
        German&2016\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \vspace{1cm}
       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
     \arrayrulecolor{tableHeadings}
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{tableHeadings} \textcolor{white}{APS / AGSV Sport Participation}}  \\
     \hline
     Table Tennis&2014, 2015, 2016\\
Soccer&2014, 2015, 2016\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}
  \vspace{1cm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Signature
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\par\vspace*{\fill}
  {
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \line(1,0){200}& \hspace{3cm}& \line(1,0){200} \\
        Person A & & Person B \\
       \small \textit{Qualifications}  && \small  \textit{BSc} \\
        Title && Position
      \end{tabular}
  }
{\clearpage}

\newpage
```

Comment: If you replace \vspace* with \vspace then at least it will show up at the top of the last page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested as you have provided no complete example but...

```
\end{tabularx}
  \vspace{1cm}
       \begin{tabularx}
```

adds the vertical space in horizontal mode so *after* the second table.

You almost always want a blank line before `\vspace` so it is added in vertical mode

```
\end{tabularx}

  \vspace{1cm}
       \begin{tabularx}
```

then to prevent a pagebreak before the signature:

```
 \end{tabularx}

  \nopagebreak
  %\vspace{1cm}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Signature
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{\fill}
  {%%%%
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
```

MWE with help of John

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\definecolor{tableHeadings}{gray}{0.6}% previously undefined

\begin{document}
\rule{1pt}{20\baselineskip}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
    \arrayrulecolor{tableHeadings}
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{tableHeadings} \textcolor{white}{Academic Subjects}}  \\
    \hline
        Mathematical Methods&2016\\
        Chinese Second Language&2015\\
        Chemistry&2016\\
        Specialist Mathematics&2016\\
        English as an Additional Language&2016\\
        German&2016\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}

\vspace{1cm}

       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
     \arrayrulecolor{tableHeadings}
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{tableHeadings} \textcolor{white}{House Participation}}  \\
     \hline
        Mathematical Methods&2016\\
        Chinese Second Language&2015\\
        Chemistry&2016\\
        Specialist Mathematics&2016\\
        English as an Additional Language&2016\\
        German&2016\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}

  \vspace{1cm}
       \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xr}
     \arrayrulecolor{tableHeadings}
      \multicolumn{2}{l}{\cellcolor{tableHeadings} \textcolor{white}{APS / AGSV Sport Participation}}  \\
     \hline
     Table Tennis&2014, 2015, 2016\\
Soccer&2014, 2015, 2016\\
  \hline
  \end{tabularx}

\nopagebreak
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   Signature
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\vspace{\fill}
  {\noindent
      \begin{tabular}{ccc}
      \line(1,0){200}& \hspace{3cm}& \line(1,0){200} \\
        Person A & & Person B \\
       \small \textit{Qualifications}  && \small  \textit{BSc} \\
        Title && Position
      \end{tabular}
  }%
{\clearpage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple but yet hours of googling didn't help. I owe you!

Comment: @JohnKormylo you get a break at the `\nopagebreak` ? oh make that `\vspace` rather than `\vspace*` (also you probably need raggedbottom to allow the previous page to run short)